# Creating a Pandas DataFrame by splitting the original DF on different caegories

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DateFrame with `'Break_Out_Category'` as a column. This column contains four variables `['Age Group', 'Race/Ethnicity', 'Gender', 'Overall']`. Now I am trying to create four different DataFrames for those different variables. 
Ex:

```
df_by_age = df[df['Break_Out_Category'] == 'AGE Group']
```

Although, I don't want to hardcode and I am trying to write a loop for the same. Here is my code:

```
var_list = data_by_avg_days1['Break_Out_Category'].unique().tolist()

for var in var_list:
   activity_limit_by_%var =       data_by_avg_days1[data_by_avg_days1['Break_Out_Category'] == var]
   print(activity_limit_by_%var['Break_Out_Category'].unique())
```

And this is the error I get

```
Error:     activity_limit_by_%var = pd.DataFrame
   ^
SyntaxError: can't assign to operator
```

This is my first post here. So if I haven't posted the question in the right format. Do let me know, what I can do to ask in a better way.

Comment: You can't use `%` in a variable name. Try changing `activity_limit_by_%var` to `activity_limit_by_percent_var`.

Comment: This creates the name of the DF as activity_limit_by_percent_var, without considering var as a pointer. The resulting DF has values only from the final iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The essence of creating "variable numbers of variables" is using a *dictionary*. While this could be closed as a duplicate of [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables), you should know that there's a better way to do this.

One simple way of dividing your dataframe by category is to use a `groupby`, iterate over each group and load it into a dataframe.

```
d = {}
for i, g in data_by_avg_days1.groupby('Break_Out_Category', as_index=False):
    d[i] = g
```

You could also do this with a *dict comprehension* -

```
d = {i : g for i, g in data_by_avg_days1.groupby('Break_Out_Category', as_index=False)}
```

`d` is a dict of mappings, which maps a string value to its corresponding dataframe. Now, access the dataframe for, example, `AGE Group` using `d['AGE Group']`.

Here's a quick example with some sample data -

```
df

   A  B
0  a  1
1  a  1
2  a  2
3  b  2
4  b  3

d = {i : g for  i, g in df.groupby('A', as_index=False)}

d['a']

   A  B
0  a  1
1  a  1
2  a  2


d['b']

   A  B
3  b  2
4  b  3
```

Note that if you want to reset the index for each group, you can modify your comprehension a little, and add a `reset_index` call -

```
d = {i : g.reset_index() for  i, g in df.groupby('A', as_index=False)}
```